# Strange exception when store blob to mysql 5.7.16 from java

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, blob

I need help with not understandable problem with store file to mysql database into blob field:

I have a function

```
public static void saveFile(File file) {
    try {
        InputStream fi = new FileInputStream(file);
        try {
            try (PreparedStatement st = Database.getPreparedStatement("insert into files (filename, content) values(?,?)")) {
                st.setString(1, file.toString());
                st.setBlob(2, fi);
                st.execute();
            }
        }
        finally {
            fi.close();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException | SQLException e) {
        throw new DatabaseException("Problem in store file to file storage", e);
    }
}
```

It's exelent work on hslqdb and postgres databases.
But when I trying to use mysql 5.7 I dot error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '???Ҙ?C%(((?????#??<?
??wx=????R?5?ݞ?n?????o?%<?\0?L?A????Q?Y}d?(???' at line 1
```

I'm lost a deep of time to understood problem but not see any problem in code.
Possible mysql not configured correctly. This is my first experience with blobs storage in mysql.
Nevertheless postgres and hsqldb are work without any problems.

I'm temporarly rewrote function like this:

```
    public static void saveFile(File file) {
    try {
            InputStream fi = new FileInputStream(file);
            byte[] data = new byte[(int) file.length()];
            fi.read(data,0,(int)file.length());
            try {
                try (PreparedStatement st = Database.getPreparedStatement("insert into files (filename, content) values(?,?)")) {
                    st.setString(1, file.toString());
                    st.setBytes(2,data);
                    st.execute();
                }
            }
            finally {
                fi.close();
            }
    }
    catch (IOException | SQLException e) {
        throw new DatabaseException("Problem in store file to file storage", e);
    }
}
```

and it work fine on all databases. But this is bad approach (I don't know size of input file but trying to load it into memory)

Tell me what is wrong? How I can use streams to proceed with blobs in MySQL ?

Comment: This looks to me as if it could be a JDBC driver bug. Which version of the MySQL JDBC driver are you using?

Comment: I'm using 
mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar

Comment: Tried to use another driver versions:
for 5.0* and 3.1* shows exception with "Abstract method"
5.1.1 and 5.1.24 have same error

Comment: Odd.  I have to admit I haven't seen this before.  I tried generating some random binary data and saving it into a BLOB column using a stream, but I was unable to reproduce your error.  Does it happen with every file you use, or just some of them?  Can I also ask which character set you are using?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not making any special actions to change character set.
System work under windows 10 (pro, english) 
`mysql settings are:  
character_set_client utf8  
character_set_connection utf8  
character_set_database utf8  
character_set_filesystem binary  
character_set_results utf8  
character_set_server utf8  
character_set_system utf8  
character_sets_dir C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\share\charsets\`

Comment: @LukeWoodward i have same problems with AWS RDS to.
Looks like something is not correctly configured in connection setting or server setting. But I can't find what exactly.

Comment: I've tried upgrading to MySQL 5.7.17 and mysql-connector-java.5.1.40.jar, but I'm still unable to reproduce your problem.  I too am on Windows 10.  I'm afraid I don't have any more ideas about what could be causing your problem.  Best of luck with fixing it - I hope you do get to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 0):

Problem founded.
It is not clean to me where is this bug present.
In our system as part of connection establesh process was executed

```
SET @@sql_mode=CONCAT_WS(',', @@sql_mode, 'NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES')
```

This allow not escape back slashes in strings that we pass to mysql.

As only I deleted this query than blobs begin to store without any problem.